# I tried get data on VS 2017 but I get this error

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssms

I tried `BULK INSERT` to get data on VS 2017 but I get this error:

> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage

This is my code:

```
BULK INSERT [dbo].[IRS]
FROM 'C:\Users\IRS.csv'
WITH
    (FIELDTERMINATOR =',',
     ROWTERMINATOR='\n',
     FIRSTROW=2)
```

Comment: I recommend loading into a staging table where all the columns are strings and then converting to the appropriate type in the database.  Much easier to debug.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, Thanks for your reply. can you please explain more how can i do this? What i have done is convert the data type for each field but i want now to import row data, so on vs i want to : 1. upload row data 2. convert data type(already has been done)

Comment: How would you convert the data type before importing? I would do as Gordon Linoff suggests. Use the Import wizard and dump this into text fields so you can at least troubleshoot your issue easier. And if you're using VS 2017 why not just do a data flow task and use the bulk option? Are you running a Execute SQL task with this statement?